How do I rewrite this product as a sum?
I know this is kind of a trivial question, but since it is only tangentially related to my research I am asking if someone else has worked this expansion out already so I don't have to get my hands dirty and waste a few days of my time getting it right. Consider the following (formal) associative product of objects $a$ and $x_j$, which are defined such that a sum and multiplication between them makes sense and so that none of them (neither the $x_j$'s among themselves nor $a$ with any $x_j$) commute with each other:
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{N}(a+x_j) \equiv (a+x_1)(a+x_2)\cdots(a+x_N)
$$
This is a homogeneous polynomial in $a$ and the $x_j$, which I would like to rewrite as a sum. I know the individual terms will be products of terms of the form
$$
a^kx_j^p
$$
where $k < j$ and $p\in\{0,1\}$. Obviously, the first term will be $a^N$, and the last term will just be a product of all the $x_j$. For small $N$, the expansion can be done by hand without much effort, but I would really like to have a general formula.

The no commutativity constraint is very intriguing.  What is the source of this problem?

@user2661923 It comes from mathematical physics. In particular, the $a$ are differential operators acting to the right and the $x_j$ are elements of a Poisson algebra. This construction is known as the Miura transformation, and the summands of the resulting sum will again form a Poisson algebra (In my specific case, a classical $W(N)$ algebra) in a such a way that the transformation is indeed a homomorphism between them.

You can write it as
$$
\prod_{j=1}^N(a+x_j)=\sum_{k=0}^N \sum_{\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}} a^{i_1-1}x_{i_1}a^{i_2-i_1-1}x_{i_2}a^{i_3-i_2-1}\dots x_{i_k}a^{N-i_k-1}.
$$
I don't know how you could simplify this further.

Oh I see, I glossed over the statement of no commutativity, let me fix the summation

I deleted my original answer, because the answer of Roland F inspired me on how my answer may be improved.
Construct two sets:
The first set is $~2^n~$ lines, where each line is the same:
x_1 * x_2 * ... * x_n

The second set is the set $~\{0,1,\cdots,(2^n - 1)\},~$ where each number is expressed in zero filled binary code.  So, for example, if $~n = 3,~$ the second set would be
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

Use the second set to alter the records in the first set as follows:
Each line in the second set will alter the corresponding line in the first set.  In the second set, each occurrence of the digit $~1~$ refers to substituting the factor $~a,~$ for one of the $~x_i~$ factors.  Each occurrence of the digit $~0~$ refers to leaving the $~x_i~$ factor intact.
In each line in the second set, the position of the $~1$'s digits determine which $~x_i~$ factors to replace.
So, for $~n = 3,~$ the first set would be altered to
x_1 * x_2 * x_3
x_1 * x_2 *  a
x_1 *  a  * x_3
x_1 *  a  *  a
 a  * x_2 * x_3
 a  * x_2 *  a
 a  *  a  * x_3
 a  *  a  *  a


It's a purely combinatorical problem. Start with
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Transpose it to pairs
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\
\end{array}
\right)^T \ = \ \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Now replace the outer list by $\otimes$ and the inner by $\ominus$
$$\left(a_1\ominus x_1\right)\otimes \left(a_2\ominus x_2\right)\otimes \left(a_3\ominus x_3\right)\otimes \left(a_4\ominus x_4\right)\otimes \left(a_5\ominus x_5\right)\otimes \left(a_6\ominus x_6\right)$$
Your noncommutative but associative expansion is performed by repeated order preserving replacements $$p_{\text{_ _ _}} \otimes (a \ominus x) \otimes q{\text{_ _ _}}  \quad \to
\quad p  \otimes a  \otimes q \quad \ominus \quad  p   \otimes x  \otimes q  $$
The result is
$$ 
\begin{array}{c}
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(a_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes a_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes a_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6 \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes a_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes a_6 \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes a_5\otimes x_6\right) \\
 -\left(x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes a_6\right) \\
 x_1\otimes x_2\otimes x_3\otimes x_4\otimes x_5\otimes x_6 \\
\end{array}$$
As you see, the index vector $1\dots 6$ are replaced with all combinations of $a_i$ and $x_i$ preserving the index order.
